# Eclipse cut/copy/paste not working

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, codepro

I have installed the CodePro AnalytiX 3.7 plugin in my Eclipse Juno.

From then in any of the Java TestCase classes the keyboard shortcuts of the cut/copy/paste are not working. 
Also the delete is not happening when I press the "delete" button on the keyboard.

The same works fine if I right click and select the operation from the menu.

In normal Java classes it works fine.

Please help.

Comment: Even I face the same issue. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem, as @Pragnani said the reason behind this is because of notepad. my notepad becomes not responding that's why copy paste not worked for me....when I restart my system. every thing goes well..

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I did not restart my system, but I went to my NotePad++ and did some copy and paste there, after that, copy and paste in my Eclipse suddenly worked again.  Weird!  But thanks for the tip!