# Delete/Copy/Paste do not work in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse-juno

It seems to be a similar problem as the one described in 
[Eclipse cut/copy/paste not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715039/eclipse-cut-copy-paste-not-working). However, the problem does not seem to be related to CodePro AnalytiX plugin.

At some point after process of debugging, copy&paste and delete keys do not work. Also from Edit menu these options are hidden.

After restart of Eclipse everything works fine again.

System : Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1
Eclipse Juno Service Release 2, updated.

A hint given in [Eclipse Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/895704/), e.g. remove key bindings in Eclipse, does not seem to be a solution because it just removes these shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

This is more often than not a memory issue and I had it recently also. I resolved it by doing the following:

1. Open the eclipse.ini in the root of your Eclipse installation
2. Increase you memory to at least more than you have now, for example

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m

This worked for me...

Comment: I changed my eclipse.ini file to:
`org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
**-Xmx1024m**`
Let's see how it works now.

Comment: If that doesn't work, recreate you project workspace from scratch (metadata could be corrupt) and otherwise reinstall eclipse which could also be corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will accept your question after some tests.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error appeared after the proposed fix. I will keep looking for the solution.