# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Copy/paste is not working

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM worklight enterprise edition in Eclipse Juno.

Sometimes cut, copy and paste keyboard shortcuts are not working in my workspace. At the same time the user is allowed to paste the copied content using mouse action Right click -> paste.

The clipboard contents are getting pasted in some other file other than where I am pasting it and makes me to search through all over the application where it is reflected.

Any solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: Is this question resolved? Please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Worklight issue, but more Eclipse-related.
There [are all sort of reports about it](https://www.google.com/search?q=eclipse%20juno%20copy%20paste%20doesn%27t%20work&oq=eclipse%20juno%20copy%20paste%20doesn%27t%20work&aqs=chrome..69i57.8277j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)...

You can try these solutions:

- http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingchyne/2012/12/copy-paste-feature-in-eclipse-juno-sr1/
- [Delete/Copy/Paste do not work in Eclipse Juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208300/delete-copy-paste-do-not-work-in-eclipse-juno)

Sometimes restarting Eclipse, creating a new workspace or using a freshly unzipped copy works too...