# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Search option is not working

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

using IBM worklight enterprise edition in Eclipse Juno.Find & replace (ctrl+f) is not working often and issue still exist even after restarting the eclipse. It automatically resumes the issue and starts to work fine without doing any changes in the eclipse or restarting eclipse.

Any solutions or updates to fix this instability?

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the same issue as in: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Copy/paste is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403033/ibm-worklight-6-0-copy-paste-is-not-working)

Not at all related to Worklight.

Answer (score 0):

WL Studio is just an Eclipse plugin, and I doubt it's causing this issue. One way to find out is just grab another Eclipse Juno instance and try it there. If it works, install studio there and try again. If it's still working, use that instance instead and just move your workspace over.